# Can't find the bug with the command "cat" in my noob python code

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

I am implementing a Shell using Python and I am having a little bug that it's been hours I am trying to fix but can't figure out the problem.

when I run my program and I start typing a line with "cat" Command, everything works well until I put a space between the stdout and the name of the file.

for example :

1)`cat <test >toto`  Runs perfectly and now toto has what's inside test.

2)`cat < test >toto`  Run  perfectly and now toto has what's inside test.

3)`cat < test > toto`  Runs perfectly and now toto has what's inside test, but I get the following line in the terminal ( cat: toto: input file is output file)

4)`cat <test > toto`  Doesn't work and I get the same line ( cat: toto....)

What's wrong when I put a space between ">" and the name of the file, why does it keep saying that input file is the same as output file ?! 
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

 import os
 import sys
 from shutil import copyfile
 def main():
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("%% ")
        line = input()
        line2 = line[0:len(line)]
        line = ""
        dirs = os.listdir()
        d = ""
        for j in range(0, len(dirs)):
            d += dirs[j] + " "
        for i in range(0, len(line2)):
            if line2[i] == "*":
                line += d
            else:
                line += line2[i]
        args=list(filter(None,line.split(" ")))
        list_arg=[]  
        src=""
        dst=""
        sr_c=0
        ds_t=0  
        cmd=args[0]
        for temp in args:
            if temp=="<":
                sr_c=1
                src=args[args.index("<")+1]             
            elif temp[0]=="<":
                sr_c=1
                src+=temp[1:]
            elif temp==">":
                ds_t=1
                dst=args[args.index(">")+1]
            elif temp[0]==">":
                ds_t=1
                dst+=temp[1:]
            else:
                list_arg+=[temp]
        if ds_t:
            output=os.open(dst,os.O_CREAT |os.O_WRONLY |os.O_TRUNC)
        else: output=1

        if sr_c:
            inputt=os.open(src,os.O_RDONLY)
        else: inputt=0

        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid == 0:
            os.dup2(inputt,0)
            os.dup2(output,1) 
            os.execvp(cmd,list_arg)
        else:
            os.waitpid(pid,0)       
    sys.stdout.write("Bye!\n")
    sys.exit(0)

      main()
```

Comment: I suggest you learn he to derby your own code. Add print statements to your code to find out what it is doing. Or use a debugger.

Comment: I used prints everywhere, still can't find what's the problem.

By priting list_arg to see what's inside too

Comment: use more `print()` and print what you have in all variables, and which part of code is executed. OR learn how to use debugger :)

Comment: I put `print(list_arg)` before `fork()` and for `cat <test >toto` I got `['cat']` but for `cat < test > toto` I got `['cat', 'test', 'toto']`  - so there is difference. It may mees then to input and output you didn't assign `test` and `toto` but probably empty string (for both). So better use `print()` again and check `src` and `dst`.

Comment: @furas but when I do cat <test >toto ( no spaces ) it works well ! eventho list_arg has only cat inside ! Also < test > toto works well and list_arg has cat,test and toto inside. But only when I put space between ">" and toto, without having space between "<" and test, it doesn't work ? that makes me crazy

Comment: Of course everything because you use `line.split(" ")` so you get `>` and `toto` as separated elements.

Comment: I use line.split(" ") to remove all the spaces between arguments ! Otherwise if I write cat       <test     >toto  it won't work, I just wanted to ignore all the spaces and get the arguments directly into my list.

Comment: your code doesn't work for me if I put space after `<` and after `>`

Comment: @furas The code works when I use spaces betwene both. And I made a detector to detect the right file if there is no space between "<" or ">" and the name of the file, otherwise it will count and it will say can't find file <*.

Comment: as for me problem is because you don't remove `test` and `toto` from `list_arg` and then you run `cat test toto` so `cat` reads from `toto` but you also assign `toto` to `dst` and to `output` so `cat` see that it write to `toto`

Comment: try directly in system shell `cat toto >toto` and you get the same error.

Comment: @furas I don't know if I get you clearly.. But what I need to do is to remove the name of the files from list_arg when there is space? So list_arg gets only 'cat' inside instead of 'cat' 'test' 'toto', right ?

Comment: yes, I create example with `iter()` to show how to do it.

Comment: @furas waiting for your example, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cat < test > toto` problem is that you don't remove `test` and `toto` so you get `['cat', 'test', 'toto']` and you assign `test` and `toto` to `stdin`, `stdout` so finally system see this as `cat test toto <test >toto` so you read from `toto` and write to `toto`

You can use `data = iter(args)` to create `iterator` which you can use with `for temp in data` as before but you can also use `next(data)` to get next element from data and `for` will skip this element - so it doesn't add this element to `list_arg`

```
import os
import sys
from shutil import copyfile

def main():
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("%% ")
        line = input()

        dirs = os.listdir()
        d = " ".join(dirs)

        print('[DEBUG] d:', d)

        new_line = ""

        for char in line:
            if char == "*":
                new_line += d
            else:
                new_line += char

        args = list(filter(None, new_line.split(" ")))

        list_arg = []

        src = None
        dst = None

        cmd = args[0]

        data = iter(args)

        for temp in data:
            if temp == "<":
                src = next(data)
            elif temp[0] == "<":
                src = temp[1:]
            elif temp == ">":
                dst = next(data)
            elif temp[0] == ">":
                dst = temp[1:]
            else:
                list_arg.append(temp)

        if dst:
            output = os.open(dst, os.O_CREAT |os.O_WRONLY |os.O_TRUNC)
        else:
            output = 0

        if src:
            input_ = os.open(src, os.O_RDONLY)
        else:
            input_ = 1

        print('[DEBUG] src:', src)
        print('[DEBUG] dst:', dst)
        print('[DEBUG] arg:', list_arg)

        pid = os.fork()

        if pid == 0:
            os.dup2(input_, 0)
            os.dup2(output, 1)
            os.execvp(cmd, list_arg)
        else:
            os.waitpid(pid, 0)

    sys.stdout.write("Bye!\n")
    sys.exit(0)

main()
```

Comment: Your code is not working, try with any command like echo * or cat <toto >test
list_arg will have something like ['o']

or even echo * will have [all files in my repository] in one string..

Comment: you do the same in `for j in range(0, len(dirs)): d += dirs[j] + " "` - it creates string with all files in directory. So `echo *` in your program do the same. Remove lines with `print('[DEBUG]..')` and you get exactly the same result in my program.

Comment: Ok I see :) Thank you for you help, I know now how to use iterators in Python. Excuse my first code above, it's been 2 days for me with Python.

Comment: BTW: see [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit). Maybe you find something interesting in source code.